# querying data from change data capture Tables

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I created the CDC on many related tables, and then I move it to a permanent storage tables. but I need to query those tables to get all the records that were updated in the same transaction, say I have Person->Worker. When I update an entity 2 records will be added to each table, if many updates were done on those tables, I will end up with many rows

how I can connect the same record in the person to the record that was updated with it in the worker....

Thanks

Comment: Please post your tables structure or your attempt at a query. Something to work with. It's going to be difficult to help you without those basic items.

Comment: let me rephrase my question: is there a unique value to collect all the rows for the same entity from different tables that were updated in the same transaction, is __$Start_lsn the same in all tables that were updated in the same transaction..... I will try to get a structure and try to post it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.....

__$Start_lsn is a unique value between all the tables that have been updated with the same transaction, so it can be used as a primary-foreign key relation to connect tables.

the problem with my tables was that the main table and the subtables were updated in two different transactions.

Thanks